# How to modify poll time for materials in GoCD pipeline?

Tags: go-cd, thoughtworks-go

I created `GoCD` pipeline.
Material type is: `Github`
Poll changes: True

Default polling time is 1 min.

I want to change poll time to 5 minutes for this pipeline only?

Comment: I'm curious though. Why would you want to change or set a new value for polling?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [configuration reference](https://docs.gocd.org/current/configuration/configuration_reference.html#config-repo-git), there is no option to configure polling per git repository.

If your network topology allows it, you could also disable polling entirely and [set up a webhook in github that notifies GoCD of new commits](https://api.gocd.org/current/#hosting-your-repository-on-github-or-github-enterprise).